# Difference between passing string S and string S[ ] in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

```
void str(string S[])
{    
    S=S+"jg";
    cout<<S; 
}
```

In the above code, it throws me an error. I understand because I am passing the pointer S. But, when I remove the square brackets off, it doesn't throw me an error. What is the reason?

Comment: a kitten and a box full of kittens is not the same thing

Comment: a string and an array of strings are completely different things in c++...

Comment: how are you calling the str function?? update the code

Answer (score 0):

If `string` is really `std::string` then it have an overloaded operator for `+` that appends a `std::string` to another `std::string`.

And character literals can decay to a `const char *` which is implicitly convertible to `std::string`.

So without the square brackets you append two strings, and

```
S = S + "jg";
```

is really equivalent to

```
S = operator+(S, std::string("jg"));  // Add S and "jg", assign result back to S
```

Which is equivalent to

```
S += "jg";
```

---

As for the reason it doesn't work with the square brackets, it's because then `S` is indeed a pointer, it's a pointer to `string` (i.e. `string*`).

Character literals are really arrays of constant characters, and as any array they decay to pointers to their first element.

That means the expression `S + "jg"` is trying to add values of the types `string*` and `char const*`, which is not possible and you get an error because of that.

Comment: Noce theory, but did you try to compile this code? I'm afraid it just won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly

```
/*
    accepts array of strings, but you must specify the size also
    other wise function won't know the size of array;

    example: 
        std::string[] arrOfStrings = {"venkat", "chary", "padala"};

        str( arrOfStrings );


        with size parameter;

        str( arrOfStrings, 3 );

*/

void str( std::string s[] ) 
{


}


/*
    accepts std::string 

    example: str( "abcdefg" );

*/

void str( std::string s ) 
{

}
```